# How react knows which arguments has to be passed to onChange?

Tags: reactjs, forms, onchange

this is a code snippet from a github page

```
onChangeHandler = (input, value, files) => { 
    if (files) {
      generateBase64FromImage(files[0])
        .then((b64) => {
          this.setState({ imagePreview: b64 });
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          this.setState({ imagePreview: null });
        });
    }
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      let isValid = true;
      for (const validator of prevState.postForm[input].validators) {
        isValid = isValid && validator(value);
      }
      const updatedForm = {
        ...prevState.postForm,
        [input]: {
          ...prevState.postForm[input],
          valid: isValid,
          value: files ? files[0] : value,
        },
      };
      
      return {
        postForm: updatedForm,
        formIsValid: formIsValid,
      };
    });
  };
```

this is used like this for input

```
        <Input
          id="title"
          label="Title"
          control="input"
          onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
        />
```

onCHangeHandler is passed to onChange but without any arguments and yet code is working. How react knows, what are those arguments "input, value, files"?

Comment: What is the `Input` element? Looks like a custom input. The `onChange` inside that component probably has those arguments defined

Comment: which framwork you are refering to ! post here the github link

Answer (score 0):

When the arguments of a callback match *exactly* those of a handler then there is no need to assign an anonymous function simply to proxy the arguments 1 for 1. In the simplest example where an `input`'s `onChange` handler passes only the `onChange` event object, and a callback consumes only the event object, then you can simply attach the callback to the handler

```
const myCallback = event => { /* handle event object */ }

...

<input type="text" onChange={myCallback} />
```

To see what I mean about proxying the arguments, here is a nearly equivalent version

```
<input type="text" onChange={event => myCallback(event)} />
```

Hopefully it is clear that for this scenario it is redundant (*maybe even a bit silly*) to use an anonymous function *just to ferry* a variable *from* the handler *to* the callback when the callback function can be directly attached to the handler.

Now with the case of the `Input` component and the attached handler, it is apparent the `onChange` handler of the `Input` component is passing between 0 and 3 values, in the specified order, to a callback.

```
onChangeHandler = (input, value, files) => { /* callback logic */ }

...

<Input
  id="title"
  label="Title"
  control="input"
  onChange={(input, value, files) => this.onChangeHandler(input, value, files)}
/>
```

Since the handler *and* callback function signatures match we can directly attach the `onChangeHandler` callback to the `Input`'s `onChange` handler.

```
<Input
  id="title"
  label="Title"
  control="input"
  onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
/>
```